# Greatest values in a matrix, row by row - matlab

Tags: matlab, max

I have an m-by-n matrix. For each row, I want  to find the position of the k greatest values, and set the others to 0.

```
Example, for k=2
                     I WANT
[1 2 3 5            [0 0 3 5
 4 5 9 3             0 5 9 0
 2 6 7 1]            0 6 7 0 ]
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it easily using the second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
data = [ 1     2     3     5
         4     5     9     3
         2     6     7     1 ];
k = 2;

[M N] = size(data);
[~, ind] = sort(data,2);
data(repmat((1:M).',1,N-k) + (ind(:,1:N-k)-1)*M) = 0;
```

In the example, this gives

```
>> data

data =

     0     0     3     5
     0     5     9     0
     0     6     7     0
```

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't exactly call that "easily". There's quite some index trickery involved `;-)`. Also, I wouldn't know what the code was doing when reading it, but that might be due to my Matlab ignorance...

Comment: SOLVED:
Q=[1,2,3,5;
   4,5,9,3;
   2,6,7,1 ];.........................
k=0.7; [m,n]=size(Q);........................
[SORT,I]=sort(Q,2,'descend');.......................
Q(I>floor(n*0.5))=0;

Comment: @rubenvb Yes, linear indexing (i.e. using a single index to access matrix entries) is a little tricky... but quite powerful once you get used to it! :-)

Comment: @luis I was more confused about the whole repmat thing. Anyways, I'll get back to my supersimple Numpy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`prctile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html) command to find the threshold per-line.
`prctile` returns percentiles of the values in the rows of `data` and thus can be easily tweaked to return the threshold value above which the `k`-th largest elements at each row exist:

```
T = prctile( data, 100*(1 - k/size(data,2)), 2 ); % find the threshold
out = bsxfun(@gt, data, T) .* data; % set lower than T to zero
```

For the `data` matrix posted in the question we get

```
>> out
out =

 0     0     3     5
 0     5     9     0
 0     6     7     0
```